# How to update text inputs via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

Okay so I have 5 inputs.  Amount ( bet ), Chance, Multiplier ( pay ), Profit, and Slider.

Right now my slider updates the win % which is what I want it to do.  BUT, when I use the slider to update the win % it doesn't update the other inputs.  It only updates the other inputs when I use the text-input to update the win %.

See code below:

Slider jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $chance_txt = $('#chance'),
$chance_slider = $('#chanceslider').on('change', function() {
    $chance_txt.val($chance_slider.val());
});
</script>
```

Text Inputs jQuery code ( don't question the formula or any of the maths, they're fine ):

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        function updateValues() {
            // Grab all the value just incase they're needed.
            var chance = $('#chance').val();
            var bet = $('#bet').val();
            var pay = $('#pay').val();
            var profit = $('#profit').val();

            // Calculate the new payout.
            pay = (999/(parseFloat(chance)+0.45))*100/1000;


            // Calculate the new profit.
            profit = bet*pay-bet;
            profit = profit.toFixed(6);

            $('#chance').val(chance);
                            $('#bet').val(bet);
            $('#pay').val(pay);
            $('#profit').val(profit);
        }


        $('#chance').keyup(updateValues);
        $('#bet').keyup(updateValues);
        $('#pay').keyup(updateValues);
        $('#profit').keyup(updateValues);



    });
</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<label for="bet">Bet Amount</label>
    <input type="text" name="bet" id="bet" class="text" placeholder="Amount">
</div>
<div class="form-box">
<label for="pay">Multiplier </label>
<input type="text" name="pay" id="pay" class="text" placeholder="Payout - 2X Default">
</div>
<div class="form-box last">
<label for="profit">Profit </label>
<input type="text" name="profit" id="profit" class="text" placeholder="Profit">
  </div><!-- End Box -->
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="form-box">
<label for="chance">Win Chance (%)</label><input type="text" name="chance" id="chance" class="text" value="50">
</div>

<p>Slide to choose win chance or enter it in the input!</p><br><input type="range" id="chanceslider" class="vHorizon" step="0.01" min="0.01" max="98" style="background-color: #00aec8; width: 50%;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't called your function!

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xnGBg/).

**JS:**

```
var $chance_txt = $('#chance'),
    $chance_slider = $('#chanceslider').on('change', function () {
        $chance_txt.val($chance_slider.val());
        // Grab all the value just incase they're needed.
        var chance = $('#chance').val();
        var bet = $('#bet').val();
        var pay = $('#pay').val();
        var profit = $('#profit').val();

        // Calculate the new payout.
        pay = (999 / (parseFloat(chance) + 0.45)) * 100 / 1000;


        // Calculate the new profit.
        profit = bet * pay - bet;
        profit = profit.toFixed(6);

        $('#chance').val(chance);
        $('#bet').val(bet);
        $('#pay').val(pay);
        $('#profit').val(profit);
    });
```

Comment: Accepted it as an answer.  Another question: how could I make them <p> instead of text-inputs?  I tried just changing it but it doesn't work then.

Comment: When I use that code my text-input for chance no longer works.. :(  Why?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
$chance_slider = $('#chanceslider').on('change', function() {
    $chance_txt.val($chance_slider.val());
    updateValues();
});
```

And either move that code into the `ready` handler (best option) or move the `updateValues()` declaration out of the `ready` handler, so that `updateValues()` will be in scope.

You said "don't question the formula", but you do have redundant code in `updateValues()` - you retrieve the values of `#pay` and `#profit` into the `pay` and `profit` variables, but don't use them, instead overwriting them with the values from the formulae. Also, after you calculate the profit you set `#chance` and `#bet` to the values that they already had. Also it seems odd to have keyup handlers on `#pay` and `#profit` when their user-entered values are ignored - why are those fields even enabled if anything the user tries to type is immediately overwritten with the calculated values?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I forgot that `updateValues()` would be out of scope because it is declared inside the ready handler. You could move the slider `.on()` code into the ready handler too. (Answer updated.)